# Razor syntax - using two variables in string

Tags: c#, razor

```
SomeObject record = new SomeObject();
record.value1 = 1;
record.value2 = "hello";

<td><input type="checkbox" id="indicator_@record.value1_@record.value2" /><td>
```

What is the proper razor syntax to create a checkbox with an id of "indicator_1_hello"?

When attempting this way, it says the object doesn't contain a definition for value1_ (understandable) and when I tried "indicator_@record.value1@_@record.value2" if had a runtime error about something named _ not existing in the context (again, understandable).

edit:

As a temporary solution I've done:

```
SomeObject record = new SomeObject();
record.value1 = 1;
record.value2 = "hello";
var combined = String.Format("{0}_{1}", record.value1, record.value2);

<td><input type="checkbox" id="indicator_@combined" /><td>
```

I am still curious if you can do it all inline though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
@{
    // just for testing
    var record = new { value1 = "foo", value2 = "bar" };
}

<input type="checkbox" id="indicator_@( record.value1 + "_" + record.value2 )">
```

Gives: `<input type="checkbox" id="indicator_foo_bar">`

Just make sure that you aren't building an ID which would be better auto-generated by the natural hierarchy of your view model. Most of the time, you shouldn't need to manually construct IDs in your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something like this, I'd suggest adding that field (i.e. CheckboxID) to your model and populate it on the server side, before passing it to the view.