# CSHTML use C# variable in element ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web

Lets say I have a for-loop to generate elements in a table:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i+=2) {
  <tr>
    @{var a = Model.ElementAt(i); var b = Model.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);}
    <td>
      <div id="r@i" class="rack-container">
        ...              
      </div>
      <div id="s@i" class="rack-selector fade">
        ...                   
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      @if (b != null) {
        <div id="r@i+1" class="rack-container">
          ...              
        </div>
        <div id="s@i+1" class="rack-selector fade">
          ...                   
        </div>
      }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

The problem is that the element is literally assigned "r@i" instead of "r1","r2"..."rN" and so on. Is there any way to combine text and a variable as an element ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
<div id="s@(i + 1)" class="rack-selector fade">
```

It might be worth having a quick read of [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/a/15278992/1200316 literally seconds after posting. Thank you, I promise I will try to look harder next time :D